# Can I use a switch rated as 250VAC 25A to switch 50VDC 25A?

Tags: switches, dc, ac, safety, arc

I am looking for a switch that can handle 25A continous current, the voltage will be maximum 50VDC, most often about 46VDC, and it will be used to switch on two dc-dc converters that have no load connected. The load will be switched on after the main switch is on.

Is this safe?

Switch:
http://www.ebay.com/itm/291078954518?_trksid=p2059210.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT

Comment: You are using an eBay link as a reference. This is a problem, because the auction will expire, the link will die, the context will be lost and this thread will become useless. Please include a summary, which will stay on EE.SE after the eBay auction expires.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most often see dual ratings on relays rather than switches (though you do see them on some switches).  In general the DC rating of a relay is about 10%-15% the AC rating for the same current.

For instance, taking a random selection of relays from my bits box:

- 16A, 250VAC / 30VDC
- 10A, 250VAC / 30VDC
- 12A, 250VAC / 24VDC

So for 50VDC and 25A the equivalent AC switch would be around 500VAC and 25A.

So no, you can't really use that switch.

Answer (score 3):

Mechanical devices (switches, relays, etc.) rated for AC use need to be derated *strongly* when used with DC since lack of zero crossing means that arcs are harder to extinguish. In some cases the derating required may effectively make it unusable with DC under *any* conditions. Consider finding a part properly rated for DC instead.

Comment: How about a switch that is rated at 12VDC and 25A? Would this be okey? otherwise do you know where i can find a proper switch for this application? Thank you.

Comment: @PeterBjarnholt: Using a device rated for a lower voltage could mean that the flow will not stop when the device is deactivated since the arcing would persist. This could also result in a fire if the temperature gets too high due to heat generated by the arc. I don't know where you're located, but I would try looking in hardware stores or surplus stores for an appropriate switch.

Comment: But if there is no load connected except a dc-dc converter in standby, would there still be a risk of such an arc?

Comment: @PeterBjarnholt: Arcing is dependent on voltage, not current.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to get away with this switch if you can arrange it so that it never actually switches (breaks or makes) the 25A. It is okay for it to **carry** 25A DC.

This might be possible if you could use enable inputs on the DC-DC converters to only enable the converters after the 50V is present and to disable them before (or within a few milliseconds after) the switch is flipped 'off'.

Comment: The converters i am refering to is the common 600w boost converter easily found on ebay. The only control is two potentiometers, one to control current and one for voltage (CC-CV). So do you think the switch could handle to turn these on and off if they have no load connected to the outputs?

Comment: @PeterBjarnholt Perhaps. It's really hard to tell (if there's a large capacitor on the boost converter input the switch could weld). If anything goes wrong you'll be responsible since the switch is not clearly rated for the current. You can always try to measure the characteristics and that will result in less guesswork. Potential problems (assuming no load on the DC-DC converters) would be welding from input capacitance or arcing when they are switched off. Why don't you use a small switch to control a big fat MOSFET?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I figure my own rating conversions:
Your 250v switch with 25amp rating:
The dc equivalent of 250vac is 250 x .707 = 176.75 vdc.  So to find an equivalent rating for 50vdc:
50/176.75 = .2829
.2829 times the 250vac 25amp rating = 7.0725amps @ 50vdc.  Arcing is more prevalent at higher voltages and currents, so you are safer using a higher voltage switch for a lower voltage application.  However switch life is directly associated with how much current is being switched, and your dc loads which typically causes more currents will cause shortened life.  I have used these calculations with few problems.  Just try to switch when currents are low when possible, otherwise just be prepared to replace a switch from time to time...